# Remove entries and line from list of data?

Tags: excel, replace

I have a LONG list of URLS. I need to remove quite a few of them. I can get as far as simply doing a find and replace where all the offending entries are `replaced` with nothing, thereby `removing` them. But I really need the empty line removed as well.

Eg to start with I have;

> www.bob.com
>   www.fred.com
>   www.harry.com

at the moment I can do;

> www.bob.com
>
> www.harry.com

what I need is;

> www.bob.com
>   www.harry.com

Comment: What language/environment are you doing this in? How are you doing the current find/replace approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in Excel. Paste the data into a new worksheet. Add a blank row at the top. Highlight the data. Click AutoFilter. Filter by non-blanks. The blank rows are now gone. Copy the data. Paste into notepad.